# Unable to get jQuery '+variable+' within selector working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change images based on the first character inside an h2 tag that corresponds to the id of a collection of images within a div called jquery_image

If I have the following code then my images will change as expected

```
$(".jquery_image img:not([id=1)").hide();
$(".jquery_image img[id=2]").show();
```

However as soon as I try to change the images using the variable jTitle nothing happens

```
var jTitle = ($(this).text().substring(0,1));   
// alert(typeof jTitle); << string
$(".jquery_image img:not([id='+jTitle+'])").hide();
$(".jquery_image img[id='+jTitle+']").show();
```

Why does this code not work? What am I doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Use `#id` not `[id=...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jTitle` needs to be completely *outside* of your double quoted strings, otherwise all you're doing is putting the literal string `[id='+jTitle+']` in your selector:

```
$(".jquery_image img:not([id='" + jTitle + "'])").hide();
```

In any event, per @Raynos's comment, you should be using a `#` selector to match on ID which makes the code much simpler to follow:

```
var sel = '#' + jTitle;
$(sel).show();
$('.jquery_image img').not(sel).hide();
```

By the way, I seem to recall reading that pure-numeric IDs aren't supported by older browsers, although they are permitted in HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".jquery_image img:not([id='"+jTitle+"'])").hide();
```

or

```
$('.jquery_image img:not([id="'+jTitle+'"])').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using differentiating quotation marks, change the `'`  to `"`:

```
$(".jquery_image img:not([id="+jTitle+"])").hide();
$(".jquery_image img[id="+jTitle+"]").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape your quotes:

```
$(".jquery_image img:not([id='"+jTitle+"'])").hide();
$(".jquery_image img[id='"+jTitle+"']").show();
```

Comment: that's not "escaping", that's closing and re-opening them.

Answer (score 0):

The expression you pass wo jquery is a standard string and has no access to the current scope's variables. You'll have to build the string yourself:

```
$(".jquery_image img:not([id='"+jTitle+"'])").hide();
```